# Compare a date stored with the present date

Tags: php, mysql

dI look for a date stored in the database. I save the result in a var but when I try to use that var later it gives me an error. I do not understand. How can I compare the present time with a time stored?

1. I look for a date that is saved in MySql database. It is saved as hours and minutes. I echo it and it works:

   ```
   $result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM consulta  
               WHERE id=3  
               AND client=1');  
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
   $begin = $row["inici"];  
   echo $begin;  
   }
   ```

   (this gives me: 15:30:00)
2. I see what is the time, now. I echo it and it works:

   ```
   $time = date('H:i:s');   
   echo $time;
   ```

   (this gives me the present time in this format: 16:38:57 )
3. I compare the two. It does not work. It gives me an error:
   Notice: Undefined variable: begin in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trobadaVirtual/begin.php on line 55

   ```
   if ($time = $begin) {  
   //do something  
   }
   ```

Comment: You're probably missing an equal sign: `if ($time == $begin) {`

Comment: I try it and it gives me the same error?

Comment: undefined variable is a notice, not an error. Post the exact notice message you get, because you're not giving us much to go on here

Comment: The warning is probably because you're not defining your `$time` or `$begin` variable. For further reading see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/3082272

Comment: Show your code in context, the error means that you have not set a value for `$begin` probably due to being wrapped in a function and not in the same scope as $time.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of DateTime class and then, get the respective timestamp and compare with the timestamp of now.

Here is a sample code.

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $dateString);
$timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
if ($timestamp  === time()) {
  // do something important
} elseif ($timestamp  < time()) {
  // other important task
}
```